# Show div when radio button checked vanilla js

Tags: javascript, forms, radio-button

A bit of a struggle here. My eventlistener only detects the "checked" change of my radio button, not the "unchecked" change. Note: Pure javascript (vanillajs) only, no jQuery.

A little JSFiddle to explain my problem: https://jsfiddle.net/kLuba37w/1/

```
<label class="checkbox checkbox--block">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="" data-show-more data-target="showmoretarget2" value="1"> <span></span> This is the first radio
</label>
<label class="checkbox checkbox--block">
    <input type="radio" name="radio" class="" value="2"> <span></span> This is the second radio
</label>

<div class="js-show-more" data-hook="showmoretarget2">
    <h2 class="h2"> Some more content</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Blanditiis ipsum repellendus, officia dolores consectetur. Error at officiis sequi iure earum.</p>
</div>
```

JS:

```
(function() {
 "use strict";

  var elements = document.querySelectorAll('[data-show-more]');

  [].forEach.call(elements, function(element) {

      element.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = document.querySelectorAll('[data-hook="' + this.getAttribute('data-target') + '"]')[0];
        alert("change detected");


  }, false);

  });

 })();
```

Comment: You have `data-show-more` attribute in a single input only. Notice, that programmatical changes don't fire events.

Comment: @Teemu I only want to check if the first radio button changes. I don't do any programmatical changes, I just listen to the (native) change event? Or am I wrong here?

Comment: @Teemu Aha ok, wasn't aware that it was in fact a programmatical change. Makes more sense now. I prefer not to wrap it into any extra element. I'll give it a try with some extra data attributes first.

Comment: Notice, that you can listen changes in `form` element too. Though that needs a bit more filtering in the handler to recognize the radio button group you actually want to listen.

Answer (score 6):

Easy way to do this, is to listen checked event an all radio buttons with name radio

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

    document.querySelector("#radio1").addEventListener("change", function() {
        alert("checked radio 1");
    });

    document.querySelector("#radio2").addEventListener("change", function() {
        alert("checked radio 2");
    });

})();
```

Comment: yes, but you're checking by element ID here :-)

Comment: @funder7 selector doesn't matter, you can target your input by any specific selector you want.

Comment: Yeah I know, but you've written "...all radio buttons with *name* radio". Not my intention to sound "picky" but IDs and names are two separate things, and both can be used as selectors.

Comment: @funder7 it is not about selectors, it is about getting all radio inputs with same name by any way you want

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.getElementsByName('radio-button').forEach(function(element) {
  element.onclick = function() {
    alert("Click detected in button #" + element.value);
  }
});
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="button1" value="1" checked>
    <label for="button1">This is the first radio</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="radio" name="radio-button" id="button2" value="2">
    <label for="button2">This is the second radio</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).